# Charting all cousins, all aunts, all uncles to degree (all living family in all lines to degree)?

Tags: chart-type

What software, website, or service can output a chart of all cousins, all aunts, and all uncles up to some arbitrary degree, like third, which would mean that you want the chart to show all people that share one of a selected person's great-great grandparents.  (And I want all of those people's siblings and spouses.)

Why?  Because I want a chart for my children that helps them understand who they are meeting at all of our various family gatherings.

Descendant charts are great for family reunions with common ancestors.  Ancestor charts are okay, but most of the people in an ancestor chart are dead.  I am looking for a chart that helps people learn where they came from and what they have in common with their living relatives.

So, in summary, and for a given GEDCOM file, the chart should ask you to select a person and a degree of cousins and then its output would include:

- That person's ancestors
- That person's descendants
- That person's siblings, their spouses, their descendants, and their descendants' spouses
- That person's aunts and uncles and their spouses
- That person's cousins up to the chosen degree, and those cousins' spouses

BONUS:  The chart is organized into a timeline with lives represented by bars that stretch from birth to death.  This would facilitate understanding of the living people's ages and generational overlaps.  Due to the number and type of people being represented, marriages and birth events that tie two parents together will have to be represented by lines that go perpendicular to the lifelines, and those perpendicular lines should be weaved under the lifelines of the people who aren't in the event.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [Gramps](https://gramps-project.org/) software v4.2.2's "[Family Lines Graph](https://gramps-project.org/wiki/index.php?title=Gramps_4.1_Wiki_Manual_-_Reports_-_part_5#Family_Lines_Graph)". However, a big downside is that you'll have to manually select "People of Interest" in all of the family lines before it will output what you want.  The graph has various options like horizontal or vertical output, output file format (e.g. pdf), include thumbnail pictures of people, and family and individual colors.

Perhaps somebody else can comment or answer how to make the graph use the selection criteria you have specified so you won't have to manually select "People of Interest" in all the family lines.  Somebody could probably change the report to do what you want through its code in the file <install location>\GrampsAIO64-4.2.2\lib\python3.5\site-packages\gramps\plugins\graph\gvfamilylines.py.

Comment: Is there a way to select *everyone* as People of Interest?

Answer (score 0):

The Graph View addon can show all connected people.

https://gramps-project.org/wiki/index.php/Addon:Graph_View