# Making family chart with everyone in it?

Tags: family-tree, gramps, chart-type

I'd like to make a chart of every family member I know of, similar to [Charting all cousins, all aunts, all uncles to degree (all living family in all lines to degree)?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/10543)

I don't want a pedigree showing all ancestors (like [Displaying exponentially growing family tree in practical way?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/10402)) but a chart including every niece, in-law, and grand-uncle I know of. I have a GEDCOM file with 140 people in it so far.

I made a "Family Lines Graph" using Gramps.

(1) Is there an efficient way to include *everyone* as People of Interest? Like a "select all" function?

(2) Are there other programs that can prepare similar charts? I think the Gramps chart isn't very pretty, and it would be great if I could, e.g., make the vertical position of family members correspond to their date of birth or marriage, or if I could emphasize some people by making their pictures bigger.

Comment: See https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/12007/fractal-display-of-a-family-tree-on-a-computer-screen, https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/14404/are-there-any-tools-that-will-display-a-complete-tree and https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/10402/how-to-display-an-exponentially-growing-family-tree-in-a-practical-way/10404#10404

Comment: None of these are exactly what I'm looking for.
The most promising suggestion is the "very messy looking tree" from Kith & Kin suggested here: https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/12007/fractal-display-of-a-family-tree-on-a-computer-screen
Kith & Kin is not fee though and I'm not sure it's worth 30 GBP: the tree shows what I want, but it's not exactly pretty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try Gramps' relationship graph (reports/graph/relationship graph)? If you want to see everybody in your database ("select all") make sure you set filter to "entire database" in the report options tab.

If you want to further customise the result with free tools, generate it in .svg format and use inkscape (another great floss software).